# XLookup on Pivot Table using pivot column headers/names instead of worksheet column letters

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, excel-pivot

I am using xLookup to pull some data out of a pivot table. Currently my formulas look like this:

`=XLOOKUP($A2,'RecT'!$A$5:$A$30,'RecT'!$C$5:$C$30,0)`

But in my pivot table, column A is called `Grade` and Column C is called `Confirmed`. It would be much easier to read the formulas if the column header/name were used to refer to the data.

Is there some version of the formula that will look more like:

`=XLOOKUP($A2,PIVOTTABLENAME[[#Values],["Grade"]],PIVOTTABLENAME[[#Values],["Confirmed"]])`

(I made up that syntax - I know it doesn't work)

Comment: If you use XLOOKUP you can click the data column (excluding header) and you'll see what it's refered as. Kinda similar to what you're asking.

Comment: That does sound like what I am trying to do, but I can't figure out where to click in the pivot table.

Comment: Have you looked into excel function GETPIVOTDATA()?

Comment: I mistaken Table with Pivot Table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see situation below:

[image: GetPivotData]

If you want to retrieve data meeting conditions of `A12` and `B12` you could use the following formula in `C12`:

`=GETPIVOTDATA("C",$G$1,"A",A12,"B",B12)`

This looks for the values in the Pivot Table in column with values of table header named `C` from the original table.

`$G$1` being the cell the table is stored.

It looks for the values where the values in data column named "A" equals the value in `A12` and values in data column named "B" equals the value in `B12`.

Change it to your needs.